# create alpha animation but not fill until button click

Tags: android, animation

I want to set alpha to all my view to `AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.15F);`
and click again to reset alpha 
I use the code below:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(fadeinout) {

            expControl.startAnimation(set1);
            seekZoom.startAnimation(set1);
            btnrotate.startAnimation(set1);

            fadeinout=false;

        } else {

            expControl.startAnimation(set);
            seekZoom.startAnimation(set);
            btnrotate.startAnimation(set);
            fadeinout=true;

        }

    }
});
```

and my animation set1 and set2 in below

```
private Animation FadeIn(int t)
{
    AlphaAnimation localAlpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.15F);
    localAlpha.setDuration(800L);
    localAlpha.setStartOffset(100L);
    localAlpha.setFillAfter(false);
    localAlpha.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    return localAlpha;
}

private Animation FadeOut(int t)
{
    Animation fade;
    fade = new AlphaAnimation(0.15F, 1.0F);
    fade.setDuration(800L);
    localAlpha.setFillAfter(false);
    fade.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return fade;
}
```

**but when animation finish reset the view to fill alpha I want alpha only change with button click**

and its not working with `setalpha()`. I want create for app for SDK 8 and above.

Thanks.

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve bro, but I think that you need to change setFillAfter to true so it will only change alphas on button click!

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic i want alpha not changeable until click on button only changeable with button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// add this line
localAlpha.setFillEnabled(true);
// modify other line like this
localAlpha.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for attenation i change this option and change if(!fadeinout) and it work